# How to center elements in gird row with custom height in tailwind?

Tags: html, css, grid, tailwind-css

In tailwind how to place Text 1 at the center vertically and horizontally without using any padding or margin ? I want to have separate widths for two rows.

```
<div class="grid grid-row-2 justify-items-center items-center">
  <div class="border-2 h-24 "> Text 1 </div>

  <div class="border-2 self-center"> Text 2 </div
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/7Zog1vjVEh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `align-content` classes https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-content : you could add `flex flex-wrap content-around` classes to your `h-24` element, and wrap your text between tags to vertically center it.

```
<div class="grid grid-row-2 justify-items-center items-center">
  <div class="border-2 h-24 flex flex-wrap content-around"><div>Text 1</div></div>
  <div class="border-2 self-center">Text 2</div
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/JiPa45W4RR

Comment: Thank You, one clarification, what exactly this flux is doing and how it is making the changes here? Is it possible to share some thoughts ?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing some classes in your code. See correct code below

```
<div class="grid grid-row-2 justify-items-center items-center">
  <div class="border-2 w-24 h-24 justify-center items-center flex">Text 1</div>
  <div class="border-2 self-center">Text 2</div>
</div>
```

I have created a demo for you. https://play.tailwindcss.com/CrUCSx4Fbp

Comment: Thank You, one clarification, what exactly this flux is doing and how it is making the changes here? Is it possible to share some thoughts ?